# How to charge a lipo battery inline with load

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, lipo

How do you charge a lipo battery while it's still connected to it's load (e.g. like all modern mobile consumer electronics) using an off the shelf lipo charger?

I have an [Accucell S60](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8wPz.jpg) battery charger and a [2S 4000mAh 25C Lipo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9BmL.jpg) battery. Both are designed for high-current RC cars where you typically remove the battery when you're done, but for my project, I want to embed and wire the battery so it doesn't need to be removed, nor the load completely turned off. How can I do this with the minimal extra wiring?

The battery has the standard HXT4mm discharge plug and JST-XH balance plug.

When charging, my application's load will be minimal and will only require about 500mA of current, so it won't be drastically stressing the battery. If possible, I do not want to have to introduce a separate power circuit to disconnect the load and power it separately.

Options I've considered are:

1. Charge solely through the balance plug, keeping the discharge plug connected to the load. [Comments here](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__95983__Accucell_S60_AC_Charger_US_Plug_.html) suggest that this charger doesn't directly support that, but [comments here](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1703714) suggest I'd need a [parallel balance extension cable](http://www.progressiverc.com/parallel-6x-jst-ph-charge-balance-cable-for-beast-umx.html) to connect the mains charge lead of the charger to the first and last pins of the balance plug.
2. Create a special adapter to wire the charger in parallel with the load via the discharge plug. I think this is essentially what option #1 does.

Is this feasible? Are there other options I'm not considering?

Comment: It is possible but not recommended, those batteries can explode violently, if something goes wrong while charging. what application is this for? bare in mind that completely discharging a LIPo will damage it.

Comment: @Alex You're overstating the risk. You likely have a cell-phone in your pocket right now with a lipo battery. Are you really worried about it "exploding violently" because you let it recharge too much the night before?

Comment: Thats lithium ion.

Comment: Not at all like a Lithium Polymer!

Comment: @Alex, Maybe 10 years ago you would have been right, but no, most phones today use Li-Po. I have a 3 year old [HTC One](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one-5313.php) that has a non-removable Li-Po 2300 mAh battery, and I'm glad to stay it almost never explodes.

Comment: And yes, Li-Po is very similar to the older lithium ion batteries. Li-Po is literally short for [lithium-ion polymer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery). Chargers for Li-Po and Li-Ion use a [similar algorithm](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries), starting with a constant-current, then switching to a constant voltage.

Comment: #2 differs from #1 because the balance wiring typically can only handle small current (due to use of smaller diameter wire). So using #2 you can charge at higher rate. But be aware  that the charger may get confused because it does not see the actual charge current but, rather, charge + load current, so e.g. termination current will be different, and it may get confused shifting back and forth between CC/CV due to varying loads. You should test how it handles that to be sure it works safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is feasible. You just need to expose the balance plug and main positive and negative terminals (using a socket that cannot be accidentally shorted out or have something inappropriate plugged into it).

One possible problem is that the charger detects a full battery by monitoring the charge current and shutting off when it reaches 1/10th of the programmed current. At the standard charge rate of 4A the charger expects to shut off at ~400mA. However if your load is drawing 500mA then the charger may not properly detect the end of charge. While this won't damage the battery, the charger could run for longer than it needs to. Luckily your charger has a safety timer that can be set to 1-120 minutes (90 minutes should be plenty long enough).

You can charge through the balance connector by paralleling the positive and negative balance wires (red and black) with the main charger outputs. However the balance plug and wiring is only good for low current (<2A) so the charging time will be longer.

Note that during charging the battery voltage will reach (or even slightly exceed) 8.4V for quite a long period of time. Make sure that your load can handle this.

Comment: it only has 1 negative, the rest are positive. I do not recommend charging through that lead. Its not designed to be used for charging, as the name suggests its for balancing.

Comment: The middle wires are 'positive' because they connect to the middle cells (center tap in a 2S battery). Some chargers do charge through the balance lead, but most of them only do 600-800mA. The FMA Cellpro charges through the balance connector at up to 4A.  http://www.revolectrix.com/m4_description_tab.htm